# Generalization of Young's inequality for convolutions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $T>0$. Assume that the stochastic process $(K(s,r))_{s,r \in [0,T]}$ satisfies $\sup_{s \in [0,T]} \mathbb E \int_0^T K(s,r)^2 \; dr < \infty$.

**Question:** Can we find a constant $C>0$ such that for all $\varepsilon \in [0,1)$:
$$\mathbb E \int\limits_0^T \left(\int\limits_r^T (s-r)^{-\varepsilon} K(s,r) \, ds \right)^2 dr \leq C \sup_{s \in [0,T]} \mathbb E \int\limits_0^T K(s,r)^2 \; dr.$$

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, one can show the result for all $\varepsilon \in [0,1/2)$. A problem is the case $\varepsilon \in [1/2,1)$.
The first idea was to use Young's inequality for convolutions. Unfortunately, $K$ depends on $s$ as well as on $r$. Are there any generalizations we can apply? Or are there any other ideas?

Comment: Using Jensen's inequality it is possible to show that the left-hand side is less or equal than $$C \mathbb{E} \int_0^T \int_r^T K(s,r)^2 (s-r)^{-\epsilon} \, ds \, dr$$ for some constant $C>0$; this implies that $$C \left( \int_0^T s^{-\epsilon} \, ds \right) \sup_{s \in [0,T]} \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T K(s+r,r)^2 \, dr \right) $$ is an upper bound. However, I don't see how to deduce the bound you are looking for.

Comment: How do you obtain the second estimate? Note that both arguments of $K(\cdot,\cdot)$ takes values in $[0,T]$. But $s+r$ may not be in $[0,T]$.

Comment: So what? Just set it zero if the first argument is larger than $T$.

Comment: Ok then your upper bound seems to be good to me. Maybe this one is already helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, the upper bound is still not helpful. I need the required estimate.